# Convert a <suds.sax.text.Text> object to a string?

Tags: python, string, suds

I have a column in my dataframe that is of type suds.sax.text.Text and I want to convert it to a string. I can't find much on how to do this, except for this [site](https://suds.readthedocs.io/en/master/suds.sax.html). Using `pandas.DataFrame.astype` does not work. I'm sure there is an easy way to do this. The documentation is just going over my head. I am using a web service to use some of its functions to return some metadata on weather stations. This metadata gets returned back as a suds object. Link to the web service is [here.](https://wcc.sc.egov.usda.gov/awdbWebService/webservice/testwebservice.jsf?webserviceName=/awdbWebService)

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.https import HttpAuthenticated
from urllib.error import URLError
from urllib.request import HTTPSHandler
import ssl
import pandas as pd

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
_URL_AWDB_WSDL = 'https://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/awdbWebService/services?WSDL'

def _execute_awdb_call(a_func, ntries_max=3, sleep_sec=5, **kwargs):

    ntries = 0

    while 1:

        try:

            a_result = a_func(**kwargs)
            break

        except Exception as e:
            ntries += 1

            if ntries == ntries_max:

                raise

            else:

                print(("WARNING: Received error executing AWDB function %s:"
                       " %s. Sleeping %d seconds and trying again." % 
                       (str(a_func.method.name), str(e), sleep_sec)))

                sleep(sleep_sec)

    return a_result

def _stationMetadata_to_tuple(a_meta):

        list_meta = [None] * len(_stnmeta_attrs)

        for i, a_attr in enumerate(_stnmeta_attrs):

            try:
                list_meta[i] = a_meta[a_attr]
            except AttributeError:
                # Doesn't have attribute
                continue

        return tuple(list_meta)







try:
    _client = Client(_URL_AWDB_WSDL)
    _stnmeta_attrs = (_client.factory.
                          create('stationMetaData').__keylist__)
except URLError as e:
    if type(e.reason) == ssl.SSLError:
        print("Warning: SSL Error connecting to AWDB web service. Skipping verification...")
        _client = Client(_URL_AWDB_WSDL, transport=_CustomTransport())
        _stnmeta_attrs = (_client.factory.
                          create('stationMetaData').__keylist__)
    else:
        raise

stn_triplets = ['878:WY:SNTL', '1033:CO:SNTL']

stn_metas = _execute_awdb_call(_client.service.
                                     getStationMetadataMultiple,
                                     stationTriplets=stn_triplets)

stn_tups = [_stationMetadata_to_tuple(a) for a in stn_metas]

df_stns = pd.DataFrame(stn_tups, columns=_stnmeta_attrs)

stns = df_stns.rename(columns={'actonId': 'station_id',
                               'name': 'station_name'})

stns['station_id'] = stns.station_id.fillna(stns.stationTriplet)

stns = stns[~stns.station_id.isnull()]
print(type(stns.beginDate[0]))
```

Comment: Could you provide the associated code?

Comment: I figured out a way to add the code that runs. Sorry about that!